# PHP/MySQL insert string into database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to insert multiple different words into a database if they are not already in the database.  I'm getting the text from a textfield where the user inputs multiple categories.  I want to split the text being passed from this textfield by comma and insert it individually into the database if it's not already in it.  Currently nothing is being input into the database.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Here is my code to split the textfield data and insert into the database:

```
$category = trim($_POST['category']);

$cat2 = explode(',', $category);
foreach ($cat2 as $new_interest)
{
$insert_user_interests = sprintf("INSERT INTO interests IF NOT EXISTS name = '". $new_interest . "'" .
                                                 "(name) " .
                            "VALUES ('%s');",
                             mysql_real_escape_string($new_interest));
mysql_query($insert_user_interests);
}
```

Comment: Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar.  Otherwise, you can still be vulnerable to injection attacks in certain conditions.  And, you aren't even escaping `$new_intererst`.

Comment: What do you mean I'm not escaping `$new_interest`? Is this not escaping- `mysql_real_escape_string($new_interest)`?

Comment: It is, but what good does it do for you if you are concatenating it in without escaping?  `IF NOT EXISTS name = '". $new_interest . "'" `

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean

Comment: Just use PDO.  Try the [PDO Wrapper class](http://www.imavex.com/php-pdo-wrapper-class/).  It simplifies things.

Comment: You're using `$new_interest` twice.  In one case, you use the return value of `mysql_real_escape_string()` and inject it into the query at `%s` with `sprintf()`.  In the other, you are are just concatenating it directly into the query with no escaping.  As CommandZ says, you should really just throw this away and re-write it with PDO.

Comment: @CommandZ Why would you need a wrapper for PDO?  The API is pretty solid as-is, unless you're making an ORM of sorts.

Comment: You don't.  The wrapper class might make it easier for him is what I was thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your `insert` statement:

```
INSERT INTO interests IF NOT EXISTS name = '". $new_interest . "'" .
                                             "(name) " .
                        "VALUES ('%s')
```

As far as I'm aware, this is not valid `insert` syntax.  (The documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html).)  I think you are confusing it with the `create table` syntax.  Instead, use `ignore` and something like:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO interests(name) VALUES(". $new_interest . "')"
```

EDIT:

Right, if you don't want to insert duplicates, then create a unique index on `name`:

```
create index unique interests_name on interests(name);
```

Then the above query will do what you want.

Comment: And this will check if the name already exists and if it does then it won't insert it?

Comment: That did not work...Should I just search the database for the value and if the result is less than 1 insert it, if not, then don't?  Or is there an easier way like the one you suggested?

Comment: @user3272438 . . . How did it not work?  If you have a unique index on `name`, then duplicate names cannot be inserted into the table.

Comment: I got it to work, I was missing `"` before `INSERT` and a `'` after the `(` after `VALUES`